# Pandas DataFrame .to_json isn't read as expected by .read_json when using option orient='split'

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am converting a pandas DataFrame to JSON for storage and want to be able to recreate the DataFrame from JSON at a later point. The original DataFrame is multi-indexed.

I'd like to use the orient='split' option which separates index, columns and data. Creating the json works fine. But when I try to read it back the index is transposed. This is obvious when I have the same number of index-columns as there are rows. Even worse if number of rows and number of cols in index differ (which they normally do...) I get a ValueError.

Is this a bug (using pandas version 1.2.4)? Is there an easy way to get around it? I would prefer to store the DataFrame in the 'split'-format.

```
mindex=['A','B','C']
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
   'B': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
   'C': [1, 2, 3],
   'vals':[1.1,2.2, 3.3]
    }).set_index(mindex)    
print(df)
result = df.to_json(orient='split')
print(result)
df_r = pd.read_json(result, orient='split').rename_axis(mindex)
print(df_r)
```

The above produces the following result

```
             vals
A   B     C      
foo one   1   1.1
bar two   2   2.2
baz three 3   3.3

{"columns": ["vals"], "index": [["foo", "one", 1], ["bar", "two", 2], ["baz", "three", 3]], "data": [[1.1], [2.2], [3.3]]}

               vals
A   B   C          
foo bar baz     1.1
one two three   2.2
1   2   3       3.3
```

Obviously the index is transposed in `df_r`

Changing to `mindex=['A','B']` or adding another row of data throws a ValueError like:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 2), indices imply (2, 2)
```

I would expect that .read_json would be able to recreate the dataframe serialized with .to_json except for the index-names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **[`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)** the `df_r` index. For this, convert the index into columns using **[`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)**, and only got the columns in the index with the **`[mindex]`** expression. Then transpose it with the **`T`** expression. Finally, define the **[`multiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html)** obtained as index with **[`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)**.

```
df_r = df_r.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df_r.reset_index()[mindex].T))
```

**Or**:

```
import json
result = json.loads(result)
df_r = pd.DataFrame(data=result['data'], columns=result['columns'], index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(result['index']))
```

Comment: That might work for the example, but if the number of indicies and the number of rows don't match, I will get the ValueError trying to create `df_r`...

Comment: Yes, I missed this. I have added new code for it; can you check?